# How similar are two DFAs? -not just binary equivalence-

Tags: regular-languages, automata, reference-request, finite-automata

Are there any measures to compute similarity (or distance) between two DFAs?

If yes, which are the main references?

I need a measure of similarity, not only a (binary) equivalence test.

"Similarity" is an intuitive concept. There are different ways to formalize it; i'm looking for ready-to-use formalizations with regard to DFAs (not NFAs, weighted automata, or general graphs!).
Furthermore, good solutions may exploit recognized languages.

I found some studies about this problem, which help to clarify the question. They involve two approaches: one from model-testing field aiming at compare languages, a second defined by authors aiming at compare structure of DFAs.

- Bogdanov, Kirill, and Neil Walkinshaw. "***Computing the structural difference between state-based models.***" Reverse Engineering, 2009. WCRE'09. 16th Working Conference on. IEEE, 2009.
- Walkinshaw, Neil, Kirill Bogdanov, and Ken Johnson. "***Evaluation and comparison of inferred regular grammars.***" Grammatical Inference: Algorithms and Applications. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2008. 252-265.
- Walkinshaw, Neil, and Kirill Bogdanov. "***Automated comparison of state-based software models in terms of their language and structure***." ACM Transactions on Software Engineering and Methodology (TOSEM) 22.2 (2013): 13.

They compute exactly what I was looking for, a metrics among DFAs, adopting the techniques developed in the model-testing field.

Does there exist any other approaches, ready-to-use, to compute similarity between DFAs? 
(Both in terms of language both of structure).

Comment: I don't see how you could define a universal similarity measure. Do you have an application in mind?

Comment: Relate to the symmetric difference of their languages? Which is regular too, and also has a DFA.

Comment: (at)adrianN I think it is a application-independent problem, automata theory is an rich autonomous field of studies.
Furthermore, some equivalence-tests among DFAs exist (such as Wp-method), but they depend on a sampling of automata (building examples of recognized languages).
I'm looking for something based on DFA features.

@HendrikJan It could be a way, but symmetric difference is more related to language recognized by DFAs then to automata features.
In the cases where i've only automata, I should sampling the languages  to compute the sym. diff., but I don't want to work with languages.

Comment: Similarity between the DFAs or between the languages they accept?

Comment: It seems as if this question asks for co-developing the question and the answer at the same time. Robott, what about the following problem definition: Find the largest value of $d$ such that there exists a word $w$ in the first language such that the edit distance between $w$ and *any* word in the second language is at least $d$. Would this make sense for your application? A value of $d=0$ represents language equivalence.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The question is clearly about DFAs, but some good solutions can be also any metric on DFAs induced by the languages they accept.

At DCTLib: Yes, it could be an answer, but I think is an exhaustive method, that is not so practicable in real scenarios.

Comment: I think the question can be improved by expanding upon which kind of measures you found and which aspects you'd want alternatives for. Reopening, though, because I think it's more clear now what the question is. (cc @DavidRicherby)

Comment: I disagree it is an application-independent problem. Different purposes ask for different kinds of similarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem seems to ask for co-development of a reasonable *distance function* and an algorithm to compute it for a given pair of languages.

The paper "**The Cost of Traveling between Languages**" by *Michael Benedikt, Gabriele Puppis, and Cristian Riveros* defines one such notion, where we are searching for the largest value $d$ such that there exists a word $w$ in the language of the first automaton such that the edit distance of $w$ to any word in the second language is at least $|w| \cdot d$. The paper gives an algorithm to solve this problem, which involves distance automata.

The paper also has an interesting related work section, with a reference to the paper "**Edit-distance of weighted automata: general definitions and algorithms**" by *Mohri*, which seems to solve the same problem without the multiplication with the word length.

Both of these definitions are reasonable from a theoretical point of view - you now only have to evaluate whether they make sense for your particular application.

---

Both of the paper have author-archived versions available without pay-wall on the web which you should easily find with your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but I can't accept as answer because they are just a  possibile ways that need to be expanded to cope the problem of metric among DFAs.

Comment: @reinierpost: If you see the references I added, you will see that problem of similarity is directly addressed.
For instance: if someone suggest me to follow a graph strategy, suggesting to see for biparted graphs, I can't accept too. Because it is a possibile strategy, but it hasn't been developed yet.
I don't want to create/develop a new method to compare DFAs, I want to find a list of ready-to-use methods, as the reported pointed out in the provided references.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the DCTLib's answer because is the best-one so far.

Here, I will add some other references that I am going to find during my researche and which satisfy the need of a ready-to-use metric/algorithm for intuitive notion of similarity between DFAs.

- Van den Bos et al. "***Enhancing Automata Learning by Log-Based Metrics***". 
   From abstract: << *We study a general class of distance metrics for deterministic Mealy machines. [...] By choosing an appropriate
  weight function we may fine-tune our metric so that it captures some
  intuitive notion of quality.*>>